# How to avoid addWindowClosingHandler/ClosingEvent unwanted reload request in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

If by mistake user presses the F5 OR
refresh button after login , he should stay on the same page. Right now he is
redirected to login page.

I have used following code to stay on same page.

But I would not like to warn the user on this situation by writing
event.setMessage() in onWindowClosing() method. I just want to make
functionality which will feel the user that nothing has happended even
if by mistake he done browser refresh.

I am looking to avoid unwanted pop-up given by [**OR HOW TO HANDLING EVENT ON CANCEL MANUALLY OF CREATED POPUP SO THAT WILL NOT RELOAD i.e. of com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.confirm("Do you really want to exit?")**]

```
    Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
     //how to prevent sending reload request OR [on cancel button MANUALLY]
    }});
```

Comment: Hello All, I have tried on internet but helps are for other than gwt, those code have implemented but not getting effect like reload(). Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. What kind of pop-up you mean?

Comment: Yes was so, display Popup with message "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.".

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you get same behavior in all browsers? Start using Activities and Places form very beginning of your project. Places assigns a 'Place' to every rendered page. So even if the user refreshes the page reloads.

Comment: Currently FF,IE8,IE9,chrome and Safari. Behavior is not same for different browser. So don't like to display but in case of using our popup even on "cancel click" browser reload. Now I am not clear with Activities and Places will you please explore.  Thanks

Comment: Here is my observation. The popup shows if you have added the WindowClosingHandler. If the closing handler is not added, I did not observe the popup on refresh.

Comment: Yes absolute, but in that case without intention user is redirecting to login page.

Comment: I have try to cancel closing event but is not woking. Any idea..    public void onWindowClosing(Window.ClosingEvent event) { if(!com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.confirm("Do you really want to exit?")){  event=null;                                   System.out.println("Cancled");
}else System.out.println("Ok");
}

Comment: Any idea how closing event handled internally as above comment I try but is not working and even on cancel button click browser reload

Answer (score 0):

In some comments above Activities and Places were mentioned as a solution for your problem. And of course it is a nice and modern one. You will find more details on GWT's documentation for these.

But if you do not want to go down that road, another solution is to use the history mechanism provided by GWT. Each "page" (rather part) of you application shall have a specific token. All you have to do then, is to create a History change handler and render the appropriate objects according to the token passed by the user's reload action. If you want to have some "memory" between user's log-outs (but not browser restarts) you can save this token in local storage and use it after user's log-in to direct her to the last page she was at.

Comment: Thanks.. Finally I have come to solution with Place Manager of GWTP

Comment: Thanks.. Finally I have come to solution with Place Manager of GWTP. But one thing here is how to control on closing event. I have tried manually which is not been controlled when using our popup even not on assigning null[event = null] on cancel button click[I have write code to control event in comment below question].